# Sorting a list of tuple according to integer value of on of the tuple members

Tags: c++, halide

I have Halide func which is iterating over a gray image and finding highest gray value in 3x3 patch. I am using RDOM to search for largest gray value in 3x3 patch, which returns a Tuple of the X,Y position and they largest gray value in the 3x3 region.

`MaxValue(x,y) = (rdom, Value( rdom.x.extent() * x + rdom.x, rdom.y.extent() * y + rdom.y), “maxValue3x3”)`

Further, I want to order the MaxValue, according to the ascending order of the maximum value (MaxValue(x,y)[2]. When I try to use merge sort algorithm, similar to how it is implemented in [sort.cpp](https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/test/performance/sort.cpp), i cannot find a way to keep the other two outputs of the Tuple(i.e., X, Y) in the same order. Is this approach in correct direction, or I am doing it incorrectly.

Thanks

Comment: please show a [mre]. Are you looking for a [stable sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort)?

Comment: I am trying to implement the merge sort, but in Halide. I have put the link of an example in the question which I tried to follow, and the exact line of code which is producing the Halide::tuple output. Should I add something else aso?

Comment: a [mre] needs to be self contained within the question without relying on external links

Comment: You can just use the index of the original array.  To convert to row/columns, just use division and modulus.  For example sort a collection of 'x,rand(x)' and is sorting on the 'rand(x)' value.  'x' is the original position.  the 'x' would represent a permutation to sort order.  If you want to find a max() position, you only need to record the position of this element with a `select()`.